# How to exclude character " in a token JavaCC

Tags: bnf, javacc

Hello i´m working with JavaCC and I am writing a token that put one String between " ". Context:

```
void literalString(): {} { """ (characteresString())? """ }
void characteresString(): {} { <characterString> | characteresString() <characterString> }
```

So i made this token to put one String:

```
TOKEN : {<characterString : ~["\", "] >}
```

The problem is I don´t know how to exclude the " symbol in the token, if I put """ it gives me error, if i put one " error again.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
void literalString(): {} { """ (characteresString())? """ }
```

use a token definition

```
TOKEN : { <STRING : "\"" (<CHAR>)* "\"" >
        | <#CHAR : ~["\""] > // Any character that is not "
}
```

Now this defines a string to be a `"`, followed by zero or more characters that are not `"`s, followed by another `"`.

However some languages have further restrictions, such as only allowing characters in a certain range. For example if only printable ascii characters excluding `"`s where allowed, then you would use

```
TOKEN : { <STRING : "\"" (<CHAR>)* "\"" >
        | <#CHAR: [" ","!","#"-"~"]> // Printable ASCII characters excluding "
}
```

But, say you want to allow `"` characters if the are preceded a by `\` and you want to ban `\` characters unless they are followed by a `"` or another `\` or an `n`. Then you could use

```
TOKEN : { <STRING : "\"" (<CHAR> | <ESCAPESEQ>)* "\"" >
        | <#CHAR: [" ","!","#"-"[","]"-"~"] > // Printable ASCII characters excluding \ and "
        | <#ESCAPESEQ: "\\" ["\"","\\","n"] > // 2-character sequences \\, \", and \n
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, that´s exactly what I was asking for. Now all my doubts are clear.